# client.login is never awaited

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

```
import discord

TOKEN = "my token"



class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'cocacola':
            await message.channel.send('cocacola espuma')

client = MyClient()
client.login(TOKEN)
```

and I get this error:

> ```
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:/Users/Aorus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/discbot.py", line 20
>     client.login(TOKEN)
> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.login' was never awaited
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Do `client.run(TOKEN)` and not `client.login(TOKEN)` on the last line.